# Javascript RegEx: How to get the name between single quotes (single quotes not included)

Tags: javascript, regex

So I have this string

```
"Account(name=u'John Doe', firstName=None, accountNumber=None, middleName=None, lastName=None, blah=None, blah=None, blah=Identification(blah=u'None', blah=u'2016-02-29', blah=1, blah=u'2313', name=u'Passport'), blah=Address(address1=u'None', country=u'PH'), blah=blah(billingNumber=u''), blah=None, id=u'f10648fa-e18a-52e6-92cc-a2c0e3cb4a92')"
```

How can I get **the name only** (`John Doe`) in Javascript? I've been searching around and solving it by myself but to no avail.

Comment: Please clarify. There are many instances of data enclosed by `'`. Do you want to get only the first bit (i.e. get `John Doe` but not `None` from `blah=u'None'`)?

Comment: Tell the python guy he should use `json.dumps`, not `repr`.

Comment: Why the downvotes? It is a polite and clear question from an user who is not on SO 24/7. It could be hard to google the answer directly.

Comment: @JanTuroň I did not downvote, but maybe because the OP did not show what he had tried. It was also very unclear what he was asking for before he edited it. It just gave the string and asked how to extract `John Doe`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `split()`, below is an example.

```js
var text = "Account(name=u'John Doe', firstName=None, accountNumber=None, middleName=None, lastName=None, bankDetail=None, contactNumber=None, identification=Identification(placeOfIssue=u'None', expiryDate=u'2016-02-29', type=1, number=u'2313', name=u'Passport'), address=Address(address1=u'None', country=u'PH'), billsPaymentDetail=BillsPaymentDetail(billingNumber=u''), smartMoneyDetail=None, id=u'f10648fa-e18a-52e6-92cc-a2c0e3cb4a92')"

document.write(text.split("'")[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options. Use a RegEx:

```
/name=u'(.*?)'/
```

And get the data inside the **`1st` Capture Group**, like so:

```
string.match(/name=u'(.*?)'/)[1]
```

The whole match is stored at index `[0]`, however this will be `name=u'John Doe'`

---

Or split by `'` and get the first bit of data (this only works if the name is the first parameter):

```
string.split("'")[1]
```

Note that the data at index `[0]` is `Account(name=u`

---

```js
var string = "Account(name=u'John Doe', firstName=None, accountNumber=None, middleName=None, lastName=None, blah=None, blah=None, blah=Identification(blah=u'None', blah=u'2016-02-29', blah=1, blah=u'2313', name=u'Passport'), blah=Address(address1=u'None', country=u'PH'), blah=blah(billingNumber=u''), blah=None, id=u'f10648fa-e18a-52e6-92cc-a2c0e3cb4a92')"

var split = string.split("'")[1]
var regex = string.match(/name=u'(.*?)'/)[1]

document.write('Using .split() - ' + split + '<br>')
document.write('Using RegEx - ' + regex + '<br>')
```

Comment: That regex result includes the quotes which is not desired.

Comment: @johnjullies It does not include the quotes, see the code snippet? The quotes would only be included if you used the RegEx `/name=u('.*?')/`, however I posted `/name=u'(.*?)'/`. The data in the first capture group is the data between the `()`, and the `'` are **outside** the `()`

Comment: That is because it matches the full string, obviously the regex needs to check if the `'` exist! The capture group does not include the `'` however, so that is why there is `[1]`, to get the data from the first capture group! And that is why I added a code snippet demonstrating it! RegExr does not show you capturing groups.

Comment: @johnjullies Use [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rN9kJ0/1). See [**the demo of my RegEx**](https://regex101.com/r/rN9kJ0/1), the highlighted area in green is the 1st capture group, **it does not include the `'`s!**

Comment: Oh I see, you have to add the [1] at the end to capture the correct match. Thanks but I going with the `split` way.